# Can't install anything because of python3-minimal and language-gnome-selector

Tags: gnome, python, python3

I'm trying to install python3 (and python2) in my env but I keep on getting the following issue:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.10.6-1~22.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: 5: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up language-selector-gnome (0.219) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package language-selector-gnome (--configure):
 installed language-selector-gnome package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-minimal
 language-selector-gnome
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to fix the issue in different ways but I keep getting the same issue each time.
Thanks for any help.

edit:
I ran the command

```
sudo apt remove python3
```

tried to remove python3 and I get the following erroes:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt5gui5-gles libqt5quick5-gles
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 217 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,427 kB of archives.
After this operation, 276 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 261970 files and directories currently installed.)
    Removing language-selector-gnome (0.219) ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
    dpkg: error processing package language-selector-gnome (--remove):
     installed language-selector-gnome package pre-removal script subprocess returne
    d error exit status 127
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     installed language-selector-gnome package post-installation script subprocess r
    eturned error exit status 127
    Removing python3-commandnotfound (22.04.0) ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-commandnotfound.prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
    dpkg: error processing package python3-commandnotfound (--remove):
     installed python3-commandnotfound package pre-removal script subprocess returne
    d error exit status 127
    dpkg: too many errors, stopping
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     language-selector-gnome
     python3-commandnotfound
    Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

edit 2:
tried to install python3.10-minimal by:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.10-minimal
```

and got the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3.10-minimal is already the newest version (3.10.6-1~22.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3-commandnotfound (22.04.0) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-commandnotfound.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-commandnotfound (--configure):
 installed python3-commandnotfound package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up python3-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: 5: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up language-selector-gnome (0.219) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package language-selector-gnome (--configure):
 installed language-selector-gnome package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-commandnotfound
 python3-minimal
 language-selector-gnome
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Python 3 is part of Linux, and required by the OS. You cannot just uninstall Python 3 as you would other programs. When working in Linux there are a few options for using different versions of Python, https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-python-versions-and-virtual-environments-venv-pyenv-pyvenv-a29fb00c296f/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you read the original error messages line-by-line, you will discover these lines. All other errors --one way or another-- grow from this original error:

```
Setting up python3-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: 5: py3compile: not found
```

The key bit here is `py3compile: not found`. The `py3compile` module is provided in 22.04 by the `python3.10-minimal` package.

- The `python3.xx-minimal` package name changes with different releases of Ubuntu. Find the package for YOUR release of Ubuntu by looking at the dependencies of `python3-minimal`

There are two steps to fixing the problem.

1. Install (or re-install) your `python3.xx-minimal` package
   `sudo apt install python3.10-minimal`
   or `sudo apt install --reinstall python3.10-minimal`
2. Change the apt-marking of the newly-installed package from `auto` to `manual`. 
   `sudo apt-mark auto python3.10-minimal`